# foreach() loop causing an error in php/mysqli

Tags: php

I cannot seem to figure it out but I am getting an error in my php/mysqli stating:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in
>   /.../ on line 28

My question is that how can the above warning be fixed so that I can loop over the insert to be able to provide all of the inserts into the db:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1); 
 error_reporting(E_ALL);

 // connect to the database
 include('connect.php');

  /* check connection */
  if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    die();
  }

$studentid = (isset($_POST['addtextarea'])) ? $_POST['addtextarea'] : ''; 
$sessionid = (isset($_POST['Idcurrent'])) ? $_POST['Idcurrent'] : '';   

$insertsql = "
INSERT INTO Student_Session
(SessionId, StudentId)
VALUES
(?, ?)
";
if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
// Handle errors with prepare operation here
}                                       

foreach($studentid as $id)
{    

$insert->bind_param("ii", $sessionid, $id);

$insert->execute();

if ($insert->errno) {
// Handle query error here
}

}

$insert->close();

$query = "SELECT ss.SessionId, SessionName, StudentId
FROM  
Student_Session ss
INNER JOIN Session s ON
ss.SessionId = s.SessionId
WHERE ss.SessionId = ? AND StudentId = ?";
// prepare query
$stmt=$mysqli->prepare($query);
// You only need to call bind_param once
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $sessionid, $studentid);
// execute query
$stmt->execute(); 
// get result and assign variables (prefix with db)
$stmt->bind_result($dbSessionId, $dbSessionName, $dbStudentId);
//get number of rows
$stmt->store_result();
$numrows = $stmt->num_rows();
//fetch the results
$stmt->fetch();

if ($numrows == 1){

echo json_encode(array('errorflag'=>false,'msg'=>"Students have been successfully added into the Assessment"));

}else{

echo json_encode(array('errorflag'=>true,'msg'=>"An error has occured, Students have not been added into the Assessment"));

}

        ?>
```

Comment: Is $studentid an array?  If not it will throw that error.  Try a var_dump of $studentid.

Comment: try dumping var_dump / print_r($studentid), check if its being created as an array.  Infact looking at your code it isn't its just a value of one of the postfields.

Comment: Also I am wondering are you are setting $studentid to a single value? If so why do you need to use in an array format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional where `$studentid` is set can set the value to an empty string.  You should probably have some conditional in there to not even attempt to prepare as statement and insert data in such a case.

Answer (score 0):

When you set the value of student id in:

```
$studentid = (isset($_POST['addtextarea'])) ? $_POST['addtextarea'] : '';
```

That is not an array, just assigning a value.

What you can do is set it in an array and then input values into that array after it is initialized. Ex:

```
$studentid = array();
$studentid[] = (isset($_POST['addtextarea'])) ? $_POST['addtextarea'] : '';
```